# Session handling in GWT RequestFactory

Tags: session, gwt, requestfactory

Can somebody show me a simple example about session handling with GWT RequestFactory.
Maybe it is very simple, but I can't figure it out.

I read somewhere that I should use ThreadLocal. Well I did. Here is my code:

```
public class EC_RequestFactoryServlet extends RequestFactoryServlet {
private static final ThreadLocal < HttpServletRequest > uniqueReq =
    new ThreadLocal < HttpServletRequest > () {
        @Override protected HttpServletRequest initialValue() {
            return null;
        }
};

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    uniqueReq.set(req);
    super.doPost(req, res);
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    uniqueReq.set(req);
    super.doGet(req, res);
}}
```

And this saves the session:

```
public class Authentication {
public static void SetLoggedInUserToSession(User user) {
    EC_RequestFactoryServlet.getThreadLocalRequest()
            .getSession().setAttribute("LOGGED_IN_USER", user);
}

public static User GetLoggedInUserFromSession(){
    return (User)EC_RequestFactoryServlet.getThreadLocalRequest()
            .getSession().getAttribute("LOGGED_IN_USER");
}}
```

After the login, it is okay, but after another request, the session is empty.

So what am I missing? Or is it a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, it's working now. I made a silly mistake somewhere else in the program. The code above it's working fine.

Answer (score 6):

Or you could just use [`RequestFactoryServlet.getThreadLocalRequest()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/server/RequestFactoryServlet.html#getThreadLocalRequest%28%29).